# Roots of an expression

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I have an expression as

$1 - 2 \sqrt{1 + i r} + i r$,

where $r$ is real.

I want to find the roots of its imaginary part. So:

```
Solve[Im[1 - 2 Sqrt[1 + I r] + I r] == 0, r, Reals]
```

However, Mathematica returns nothing. But by direct substitution in the expression $1 - 2 \sqrt{1 + i r} + i r$, for example for $r = 0.01$ one can see the imaginary part vanishes.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Try `Solve[ComplexExpand[Im[1 - 2 Sqrt[1 + I r] + I r], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] == 0, r, Reals]`

Comment: Thanks. But it returns only $r = 0$.

Comment: I don't think r=0.01 is a root. Look at: Plot[Im[1 - 2 Sqrt[1 + I r] + I r], {r, 0, 0.012}]

Comment: Yes. But the imaginary part is negligible to its real part when $r = 0.01$.

Comment: "Negligible" only means small, and not always zero. You asked *Mathematica* for when it will *exactly* be zero, when you were interested in a different thing altogether.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what happens with your attempt:

```
Solve[Im[1 - 2 Sqrt[1 + I r] + I r] == 0, r, Reals]
```

> Solve::nddc: The system -2 Im[Sqrt[1+I r]]+Re[r]==0 contains a nonreal constant I. With the domain \[DoubleStruckCapitalR] specified, all constants should be real.
>
> Solve[-2 Im[Sqrt[1 + I r]] + Re[r] == 0, r, Reals]

Notice the error message. You can't use the domain [`Reals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals) when the equation to be solved contains [`I`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/I). Instead, include the domain restriction along with your equation:

```
Solve[Im[1 - 2 Sqrt[1 + I r] + I r] == 0 && r ∈ Reals, r]
```

> {{r -> 0}}

By the way, probably the most reliable method is the one suggested by @JM in the comments:

```
Solve[
    ComplexExpand[Im[1-2 Sqrt[1+I r]+I r], TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}] == 0,
    r,
    Reals
]
```

> {{r -> 0}, {r -> 0}, {r -> 0}}

**Addendum**

In the comments, the OP explained that he wanted to know the values of `r` for which the imaginary part is negligible. [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) is a better tool in this case. For example, the values of `r` for which the imaginary part is smaller in magnitude than 10^-6 can be obtained with:

```
Reduce[Abs @ Im[1-2 Sqrt[1+I r]+I r] < 10^-6 && r ∈ Reals, r] //N
```

> -0.0200012 < r < 0.0200012